# Why am I getting "ftplib.error_perm: 550 Access denied" on .rename?

Tags: python, ftp

I'm uploading a file, then I want to move it. The uploading part works, but the move attempt throws an access error. Why is that? I also tried moving a file already in the directory, but this causes the same error.

To simplify, I am "moving" the file in the directory I successfully wrote to. The FTP settings allow read/write/execute for the account, and using Filezilla I can rename files as well.

Code:

```py
import ftplib

testfile = "D:\movethis.txt";
session = ftplib.FTP('<IP>', '<U>', '<P>');
session.cwd("XXX\TestPyUpload\upload");
print(session.pwd());
file = open(testfile, 'rb');
session.storbinary('STOR movethis.txt', file);

session.rename("XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis.txt", "XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis2.txt");
file.close();
session.quit();
```

Comment: You provide the code for the client but nothing is known about the server - even though  it is the server who is generating the error message. Anyway, I would try to simplify the code to not rename by full path but only by the filename (i.e. `movethis.txt` instead of `XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis.txt`). This should  logically be the same since your CWD is already `XXX\TestPyUpload\upload`. Maybe it will work, but maybe the (unknown) server has restrictions what can be done in the upload directory (check your server configuration). Also, you better escape your `\ ` in the code.

Comment: Additionally, did you test renaming/moving the file using any existing FTP client? Does it work? Show us its log file.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I know nothing about the server. `session.rename("movethis.txt", "movethis2.txt");` does indeed work. So does `session.rename("\XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis.txt", "\XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis2.txt");` (added \ at the beginning). Strangely, when I do this, the file in "upload" also gets renamed and folder "serve" stays empty: `session.rename("\XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis.txt", "\XXX\TestPyUpload\serve\movethis2.txt");` Quite confusing..

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> session.cwd("XXX\TestPyUpload\upload");
> ```

Your current working directory is now `XXX\TestPyUpload\upload`.

> ```
> session.storbinary('STOR movethis.txt', file);
> ```

This saves the file `movethis.txt` into your current working directory, i.e. the path is `XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis.txt`.

> ```
> session.rename("XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis.txt", "XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis2.txt");
> ```

It is unknown what exactly `XXX` is. But if it does not start with a `\` it is a relativ path. In this case the names in the `rename` command are interpreted relativ to the current working directory (`XXX\TestPyUpload\upload`), i.e. you are renaming `XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis.txt` to `XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis2.txt`. Neither the source exists nor the destination directory, which explains the error thrown by the server.

> ... `session.rename("movethis.txt", "movethis2.txt");` does indeed work.

These names are interpreted relativ to the working directory too, i.e. you rename `XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis.txt` to `XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\\movethis2.txt` as you've originally intented.

> ... So does `session.rename("\XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis.txt", "\XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis2.txt");` (added `\` at the beginning).

In this case you are using absolute file names and that's why it does not take the current working directory in account, thus avoiding your original problem.

Comment: I see, thanks. But why would `session.rename("\XXX\TestPyUpload\upload\movethis.txt", "\XXX\TestPyUpload\serve\movethis2.txt");` rename the file in the "upload" folder instead of moving it to "serve"? I discovered that I get 550 when I cwd to the "serve" directory before performing the move, which I guess means I'm not allowed to write to "serve", but why does the file get renamed where it shouldn't?

Comment: @MapEngine: I don't know. I would need to play around with the server myself before I can develop any ideas about this. But in general it is a bad idea to use `\ ` as  path delimiter since the delimiter is usually `/` except for Windows servers (and even these usually except `/`). Moreover `\ ` has a special meaning (like in `\n`, `\020`...) and thus should be properly escaped in the code.